# How do I insert a \in cross reference across components?

Tags: cross-referencing, context

I am using ConTeXts project format, with each chapter using its own .tex file.

In chapter 6, I want to refer to [fig05] in chapter 9.

Looking at the wiki for [\in](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/in) there's no discussion of this. But looking at the logs interacting with references, they have two arguments (which show up as [component][reference])

Is there a way to address other components via cross-reference?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the general manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/cont-eni.pdf) I found mention of a syntax on page 207.

In my environment, I added:

```
\setuphead[chapter][prefix=+]
```

Then, in chapter heads, I titled them uniquely:

```
\chapter[chapter06]{this is a chapter title}
\chapter[chapter09]{this is a different chapter title}
```

Then, in chapter 6, I can reference figure five b of chapter 9 by

\in[chapter09:fig05b]

so long as I've turned on prefixes and have declared a chapter reference.

Comment: Just in case it's useful: there's also a special magazine about cross-referencing between documents; have a look at [the pragma website](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/magazines/mag-1103.pdf)